# div в html сам удаляет у себя класс на отображаемой странице, но класс существует в devtools

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

что это может быть? скриптов тут нет.

при наведении мышью в девтулсе на класс, на странице в бабле он отображает класс как несуществующий. стили к этому классу через css файл не применяются, если прописать в девтулсе к этому классу стили, то они применяться. проблемный класс в примере назван .wtf [image: отображение дива без класса][image: отображение в девтулс]

Comment: Желательно сделать тестовый пример (текстом) на котором проявляется проблема и показать его в своем вопросе.